# Export without texture

Tags: export, unity

I am new to Blender. I find a model. When I'm trying to render it, there is a texture. But when I export this model to unity it isn't shown. What I do wrong?

Comment: In what file format are you doing it in .fbx , .stl , .obj

Comment: @Yohello1 .fbx and .blend

Comment: Try opening it in a different program and see if the textures are still there.